# Rewriting content of an HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to JS, can't understand how to make this code work. I'm trying to overwrite the whole html source text.

```
var oldSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(oldSource); //this works, it gets the whole html

document.write(Change(oldSource)); //doesn't work, writes undefined

   function Change(source){
     for (i = 0; i <= source.length; i++){
     source[i] = "S"; // doesn't change the source[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at JQuery. It's a javascript library that makes manipulating the DOM (i.e. the html on a web page) easier. Adding the line 

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` 

to the `<head>` of your html file imports the library. Once it's imported you can call `.html()` on a DOM element and pass in the new HTML you'd like it to contain.

Note JQuery is used on over 55% of all web pages, according to wikipedia.

Comment: Are you trying to change the entire document to a bunch of `S` characters as you're iterating over a string, and if so, why ?

Comment: A function named `Change`??? Give your functions decent names so we can try to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Accipheran: Not being easy enough isn't the issue here. Not every page needs jQuery.

Comment: @adeno its probably just an exercise to see what happens. The OPs problem isn't what the function is doing but why the `innerHTML` wasn't updating.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the value of the variable `oldSource`, not the value of the `documentElement.innerHTML`.

`.innerHTML` [just returns a string that contains the serialised content of that element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) It doesn't return a reference to the content in the DOM.

Furthermore, `document.write(Change(oldSource))` is saying write the return value of `Change(oldSource)` to the document... but your `Change()` function doesn't return anything, hence it is `undefined`.

Lastly, strings are immutable, meaning you can't change their contents after they have been created. Instead, you need to build up a new string in your function, like so:

```
function Change(source){
   new_source = ""
   for (i=0; i < source.length; i++){
     new_source = new_source + "S"; //doesn't change the source[i]
   }
   return new_source
}
```

[You can check all of this out in this jfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XDzmg/)

Comment: You can change the `innerHTML` of `documentElement`.

Comment: @AndyG Hmmm, I had trouble doing it in JSFiddle and didn't verify. I'll edit that out.

Comment: No worries. It needs to be `< source.length` (and JS statements are semi-colon terminated - sorry, I know it works anyway without them.)

Comment: @AndyG Such a pedant :P Fixed the condition, but I didn't add the last semicolon as its the last instruction in the block and won't be unambiguous :)

Comment: You mean it "will be unambiguous" ;) Yes, you could describe me as a pedant :)

Comment: @AndyG - Damn you double negatives. I may have also meant "won't be ambigious". I quit :(

Comment: -1 for uncorrect fiddle, check them before answering! also, it seems you don't really know the answer

Comment: @vladkras The Fiddle does what the OP asked, but needed to be modified as JSFiddle doesn't like changing the `innerHTML` of `documentElement`. Sorry if my critque on your answer offended, but the points you raised weren't completely helpful or relevant to the OP - I was trying to be helpful.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr oh, for sure? your fiddle's `new_source` containes all document, it's not replacing your `Some content`, but alerts hundreds of `S` so I think your code is even less representative, than OP's one. Also, your global `new_source = new_source + "S";` is so newbie

Comment: The serialised `innerHTML` returns the entirety of the document, not just the text `Some Content` so it will be hundreds of 'S's long. If you can improve on the fiddle, please feel free to fork it and update your answer so we can all learn :)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr already [did it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17538059/1713660) in two ways, with `replace()` you hate so much too

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return( source );` after your for loop

Comment: JavaScript strings are immutable, so this will just return the original text.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, this line: `var oldSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;` copies the `innerHTML` into the `oldSource` variable. It does not save a reference to the `innerHTML`.

You are modifying the value stored in `oldSource`, but never applying it to the document.

In your `Change` function, you do not return any value - that is why you are getting an `undefined`. Add a 'return source;`in your`Change` function to return a value.

The other problem is that you can't change the string in JavaScript. You should make a new variable for this. You can't edit `source[i]` - you can only retrieve the value that is there.

Comment: You can use [] to access characters of a string, but strings are immutable so we can't use this to change them.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings are immutable. You can't use

```
source[i]="S";
```

to modify a string. You need to build a new string and return it.

It should be `< source.length` as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. your function must `return` something, not just change
2. you cannot change strings this way, use [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method instead
3. if you specify what you **really** need to do, our help could be more effective

**EDIT** As far as I didn't find correct working code here, I want to suggest my one

```
function Change(source){
   var str = source.split("");
   for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++){
     str[i] = "S";
   }
   return str.join("");
}
```

Maybe it's not the fastest way (though, why not) but it lets you to operate with indexes as you tried in your question.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/jUeZr/1/) for *Lego Stormtroopr*

**EDIT2** and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/jUeZr/2/) shows how to do it in one line inside the loop (without creating extra variables)

```
   for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++){
     source = source.replace(new RegExp(source[i]), "S");
   }
```

Comment: -1 for linking to W3Schools. Functions don't always have to change things, its just in this case it does. It could just as easily pass in an id, call `getElementByID` and change via that, no return neccessary. Also, it appears that the code is exploratory, not homework or production. I think the OP just wants to learn why this doesn't work.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr then write your own best answer, ah you already did it

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the new source string like below;

```
var oldSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(oldSource); //this works, it gets the whole html

document.write(Change(oldSource)); //doesn't work, writes undefined

function Change(source){
     for (i=0; i<=source.length; i++){
         source[i]="S"
     }
     return source;
}
```